# iOS App got rejected - Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

My app was already live on Appstore. I wanted to upload a new version and my app got rejected thrice due to the reason - **Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions**

Here is what AppStore says :-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFjke.png

I have updated the app privacy with the functional link of privacy policy, Also in the app description, I have added privacy policy and Terms and condition URL.

I had also included the screen shot of the in-app purchase view of the app.

Really don't know the solution, browsed several solutions and implemented the same (Such as adding app subscription screenshot, updating privacy policy).

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the links to the app store metadata only or added clickable links inside the app itself. The complaint says that they couldn't be found in "the app binary" which means the application you are building, not in the app store description

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I have not added link in my application. I am re-designing the application subscription page and will add the links there. Thanks for replying. :)